# How do I update a textbox value using values from an array?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, coordinates, getelementbyid

I'd like to use JavaScript to update a textbox value using values from an array:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        alert(pos['lat'] + ', ' + pos['lng']);

        data = pos['lat'] + ', ' + pos['lng'];

        document.getElementById("address").value = data.value;

    }, function() {

    });
}
```

My problem is that the alert displays the lat and long coordinates correctly, but the textbox value gets updated to "undefined", meaning data.value is undefined.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

- Note: I can't provide a code snippet for geolocation on stackoverflow it seems? *

Comment: I think the data should be a string , so you just assign data to it 
document.getElementById("address").value = data;

Comment: doh! that was it. thanks :)

Comment: Give me a up vote haha :)

Comment: double up vote ;)!

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    document.getElementById("address").value = data;